# How to identify which Firebase child is selected using didSelectRowAt in a table view with Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I can't figure how to identify which child from my Firebase database is being selected in the table view, and then update information under that selected child in the database.

I found an observe function that correctly displays all of the childByAutoID's for each row, but it shows every row, not the specific row which is selected and update the information under that child.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(tasks[indexPath.row].isFlagged)

    var task = self.tasks[indexPath.row]
    task.isFlagged.toggle()
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

    var flag = ["isFlagged":false]

    if tasks[indexPath.row].isFlagged == true {
        flag = ["isFlagged":true]
    } else {
        flag = ["isFlagged":false]
    }
    Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).child("tasks").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let result = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
            for child in result {
                var theKey = child.key as! String
                print(theKey)
                Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).child("tasks").child(theKey).updateChildValues(flag)
            }
        }
    })

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read `tasks` you should store the root key of the dictionary to use it later

[image]

Then do this inside `didSelectRowAt`

```
let task = self.tasks[indexPath.row]
Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).child("tasks").child(task.key).updateChildValues(flag)
```

---

```
struct Task {
  let key:String
  .....
}
```